# Toggling Auto Layout constraints - possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Is it possible to toggle Auto Layout constraints, so one can be enabled under certain circumstances, but that one can be disabled and another can be enabled under a different circumstance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, silly me. This can be achieved through the `priority` property, setting one higher than the other.

Comment: That's not the same as "toggling" it though. You can't set a zero property. You can instead just remove it and add it when you need it again.

Comment: Is that the best one can do?

Comment: @DougSmith, yes, that's all you can do if you can't modify the constraint's constant instead.